# How to get attachments and inline attachments for CaseComment via Rest API?

Tags: rest-api, case, attachment, case-comment

I have a Salesforce instance using the old CaseComments instead of a Chatter feed.
How do I get attachments and inline attachments to a CaseComment via Rest API?

I can get the CaseComments to a Case from `/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/Case/<case ID>/CaseComments`. But the `CaseComment` type doesn't have fields or relationships for attachments and inline attachments. Also, the `CommentBody` field is just plain text and therefore does not contain the inline attachments.

I managed to get all non-inline attachments for a Case via

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Title, FileExtension from CombinedAttachments) FROM Case WHERE Id = <case ID>
```

But that doesn't give me a relationship to the comments, so I can't tell to which comment this attachment belongs (I can only guess from the timestamp). I also still have no idea where I can find the inline attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CaseComments` are plain text, not rich text. It turned out that in this particular instance, rich text was added via a custom object, which I had to query in order to access the comment as rich text and to then download the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments to Case comments lie within Salesforce in the form of Case Comment Publisher component.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_case_publisher.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I access that via API? And does that work for inline attachments as well? I'm mostly interested in those.

Comment: Attachments gets stored as attachment record on the case object. Case Comments and Attachments are usual Standard objects that you can use it along with any API calls

Comment: You say "on the case object". Are you referring to what I did in my question where I select `CombinedAttachments` for the case? So is there no way to get inline attachments for the comments?